# Neo4j using Keywords for label/node/relatonship names

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I've been playing around with Neo4j recently and to my surprise I figured it is possible to set label, node or relationship name to Keyword (MATCH,CREATE,ORDER ... ). I am aware that this is very bad practice.

```
CREATE (s:CREATE{CREATE: "something"}) RETURN s
```

But my question is: "Does this result only in less transparet queries or are there consequently any possible errors? If errors could occur, why is it even allowed?"

I know it is a silly question, but nowhere in the neo4j docs I have not found the answer.

Comment: Less transparent queries, you can backtick them to make clear that they are not the keywords to a reader.

Comment: Yes, avoid using reserved words for entity names. It's great Neo4j doesn't restrict their use, but it will lead to confusion. (As a counter example VAX-COBOL has over 500 reserved words.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the syntax tree is such that the parser shouldn't ever be confused by whether it's evaluating a keyword, label, property, or some other piece.

I don't believe we've seen any issues related to this, at least from versions 3.0 and up (I wasn't around in the pre-3.0 days).